# Stream raminication with continuation if one branch breaks

Tags: pipe, stdin, streaming, tee, streams

Say I ramify a video stream to 2 `ffplay` processes

```
cat video.mp4 |  tee >(ffplay -i -) >(ffplay -i -) > /dev/null
```

Now, if I kill one of the `ffplay` process, the stream is stopped which is not what I want.

**How can I modify this command to continue to stream the video to the first `ffplay` process if the second is killed?**

PS: I am looking for a solution without named pipe (fifo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution

```
cat video.mp4 |  tee >(ffplay -i - || cat >/dev/null ) >(ffplay -i - || cat >/dev/null) > /dev/null
```

---

**Example**: to save an encrypted webcam capture and play it at the same time with possible killing of the file saving process (`openssl`) or the player (`ffplay`), I can use:

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -ac 2 -i plughw:0,0 -f video4linux2 -s vga -i /dev/video0 -f ogg - | tee >(openssl enc -k mypassword -aes-256-cbc > encrypted-capture.aes-256-cbc || cat >/dev/null) >(ffplay -fs -i - || cat >/dev/null) > /dev/null
```

You have to kill the `ffplay` process ( press <kbd>f</kbd> and then run `pkill ffplay`), not close the window with <kbd>Esc</kbd>